# Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner

Tags: smtp, exchange-2007, sonicwall, banner

I had this Warning with mxtoolbox. I know that it's not necessarily a big problem, but since we are having lots of issue with email delivery, I want to check everything.

I have a Exchange server 07 + Sonicwall.

My FQDN is office.mydomain.ca  for send/receive connectors.
When I try : ***telnet office.mydomain.ca 25*** --> **220 MYSERVER.mydomain.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 7 May 2010 10:34:36 -0400**

I can change my SMTP Banner in the Sonicwall, but I don't know what to write, if there is a specific syntax or what can be the consequence if it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

edit: Here's the result for the SMTP test:

> 220 emailsecurity.mydomain.ca ESMTP
>   SonicWALL (7.2.1.2841)
>
> Not an open relay.
>  
>   0 seconds - Good on Connection time
>    0.296 seconds - Good on Transaction time  OK - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx resolves to 
>   Warning - Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner
>
> Session Transcript: 
>   HELO please-read-policy.mxtoolbox.com 
> 250
>   emailsecurity.mydomain.ca [78 ms] 
> MAIL
>   FROM: supertool@mxtoolbox.com
>  250
>   2.1.0 MAIL ok [62 ms] 
> RCPT TO: test@example.com 
> 550 5.7.1 Unable to
>   relay for  [78 ms]
>   QUIT 221 2.0.0 Bye [62 ms]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the SMTP service of Exchange there is a special setting to override the hostname exposed by SMTP server during SMTP greeting. I think it is inthe same window of the smart host setting (sorry I don't have an exchange server at hand right now)

Comment: +1 for the only one knowing what the OP talks about ;)

Comment: http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/75/smtpbanner.jpg

(10.10.10.111 is my Sonicwall)
This is it ?

Comment: Can someone confirm please ?

Comment: Bastien974: correct, that is the window. Note that if yoi use the square brackets you override the DNS lookup.

Comment: You mean the [10.10.10.111] as it is already ? I doesn't override right now, if I click the checkbox it will ?

Comment: Bastien974: if you DON'T use the square brackets, the SMTP service will look at the DNS MX record.

Comment: The bracket are already here, but i still have "Warning - Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner" and the SMTP Banner displayed is the one from the SonicWall, so I think the Sonicwall is overriding it and the change need to be done on it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Type in the FQDN of your Domain MX Entry

Make follow on the Shell

nslookup 
set q=mx

And here we are you see the MX Host A-Record Name of your Domain
This you need to use on your smtp banner.

Something simmaler to this
mx.google.com<123.123.123.125>

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The response you're getting via telnet is different that the one you're getting from MXToolbox, but I'm assuming you've setup your SonicWall as an SMTP relay for your Exchange Server.

You can set the banner to whatever you wish as long as it starts with `220`. To have it match, just put "`220 office.mydomain.com ready`" in the SonicWall where you configure the banner (it may actually put the 220 in for you, I don't know, as I don't have any SonicWall experience).